# Python - Regex only in indented lines

Tags: python, regex, find

I've got a file with this type of structure:

```
create "layer01";
    attr "False";

create "layer02";
    other_stuff;

create "layer03";
    attr "False";
```

I already have a list of `['layer01', 'layer02', 'layer03']` and I need to check which of them has the `attr "False"` indented (which will have always this name). Is there a clean/smart way to do that?

Comment: Try this [`create "(layer\d+)";\s*attr "(False)";`](https://regex101.com/r/hyjAxJ/2)

Comment: Thank you, what If between create and attr are there other indented lines?

Comment: Then you may try using [`create "(layer\d+)";(?:(?!create)[\s\S])*attr "(False)";`](https://regex101.com/r/hyjAxJ/4)

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
^
create\s+"([^"]+)";\s+
attr\s+"([^"]+)";
```

As in

```
import re

data = """
create "layer01";
    attr "False";

create "layer02";
    other_stuff;

create "layer03";
    attr "False";
"""

rx = re.compile(r"""
    ^
    create\s+"([^"]+)";\s+
    attr\s+"([^"]+)";
""", re.MULTILINE | re.VERBOSE)

layers = [layer.group(1) 
          for layer in rx.finditer(data) 
          if layer.group(2) == "False"]
print(layers)
```

Which yields

```
['layer01', 'layer03']
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/btCPbX/1/).